# Regular expression to parse .scss function body (SCSS Parser via JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

https://regex101.com/r/KCORmT/2

### Regular expression

This is not PCRE

```
@function[^(]*\([\s\S]*?^}$
```

### Test

It works

```
@function color ($color: #f00) {
  @if 1 + 1 == 2 {
    $color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  }

  @return $color;
}
```

It does not work

```
@function color($color:#f00){@if 1+1==2 {$color:rgb(0,0,255);} @return $color;}
```

## Issue

I have to parse function from **@function** to **last curly brace**. This `^}$` will parse `}` on the new line but this is not effective with this example below (***and please example can be without new lines***). Is there any trick to parse function body without nested curly brackets?

```
@function color ($color: #f00) {
  @if 1 + 1 == 2 {
    $color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

  @return $color;
}
```

EDIT NOTE:
there may be pairs of curly brackets inside so can we filter all nested pairs of curly brackets?

Comment: Is there any limit to the amount of potential `{` / `}` nesting inside the function?

Comment: @CertainPerformance no... but there may be pairs of curly brackets so can we filter all nested pairs of curly brackets?

Comment: If the input's indentation was guaranteed to be proper, then it would be possible by checking the amount of leading whitespace of the `@function` line

Comment: @CertainPerformance input can be without white spaces and without new lines... i edited question

Comment: It looks like you'd want something like a [balancing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html) which unfortunately isn't supported in native JS

Answer (score 0):

If the number of nested levels are limited, it could be done. This, for example, handles 4 nested levels. But it will fail if there are comments containing `{` or `}`.

```
@function[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*(?:[^{}]*{[^{}]*(?:[^{}]*{[^{}]*(?:[^{}]*{[^{}]*})*[^{}]*})*[^{}]*})*[^{}]*})*
```

You could increase the number of levels by adding `(?:{[^{}]*` to the beginning (before the first `(?:{[^{}]*`, and `[^{}]*})*` to the end.

It works by matching and inner `{...}` pair without any curly braces in between - `(?:{[^{}]*})*`. Then by adding the "head" and "tail" any number of times, the number of levels is increased. Each level is optional thanks to grouping it with an `*`, that also makes it repeatable. Finally "your" `@function` match is prepended.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2FFNZf/4).

**Edit**
Sorry messed up a bit. Edited to handle multiple repetition in each level.

Comment: @Altaula Now it does :)

Comment: dude i'm fighting with your answer... can you please explain (detailed) how you did it?